# I cannot send data to a fiscal printer through the RS232 port

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm having trouble getting a raster to write to a fiscal printer. I am using python's pyserial. I write the frame in binary, I send it to the device through the COM3 port using the write function, it says that it is sent, but then I request a response from the printer and I do not receive a response, that is, the application freezes. When making the connection it says, the printer is ready to receive data.

```
     puerto = 'COM3'  # Reemplaza con el nombre correcto del puerto USB
    velocidad = 9600

    # Velocidad de transmisión en baudios
    #velocidad = 9600

    def calcular_lrc(datos):
        lrc = 0
        for byte in datos:
            lrc ^= byte  # Operación XOR bit a bit
        return bytes([lrc])

    def verificar_conexion_impresora(puerto):
        try:
            ser = serial.Serial(puerto, velocidad, timeout=1)

            # Esperar un momento para que se estabilice la conexión
            time.sleep(2)

            # Verificar el estado de CTS y DTR
            cts_listo = ser.getCTS()
            dtr_listo = ser.dtr

            # Imprimir los resultados
            print(f'CTS listo: {cts_listo}')
            print(f'DTR listo: {dtr_listo}')

            if ser.isOpen():
                print("La <link>impresora</link> está conectada y lista para recibir datos.")
                datos= b'S'+ b'1'+ b'\x03'                  
                print ("DATOS BINARIO:")
                print (datos)
                print ("DATOS HEXADECIMALES:")
                print (datos.hex())
                print ("LRC:")
                print (calcular_lrc(datos))                    
                #trama=b'\x02'+ datos + calcular_lrc(datos) 
                print ("TRAMA:")                    
                print (trama)
                print (trama.hex())
                ser.write(trama)  # Envía los datos a la <link>impresora</link>
                ser.flush()  # Espera a que se envíen todos los datos
                print("Datos enviados a la <link>impresora</link>.")
                respuesta = ser.readline().decode().strip()  # Lee la respuesta de la <link>impresora</link>
                print("Respuesta de la <link>impresora</link>:", respuesta)
                ser.close()
            else:
                print("La <link>impresora</link> está conectada pero no responde.")
        except serial.SerialException:
            print("No se pudo establecer conexión con la <link>impresora</link>.")
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Tiempo de espera agotado al leer desde el puerto serial")
```